# Role-based Permissions

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm currently trying to use Role-based permission on Micro-Integrator v 7.1.0 while calling api request, i've already managed to use REST Basic AuthHandler as shown below, which works just fine.

```
<handlers>
   <handler class="org.wso2.micro.integrator.security.handler.RESTBasicAuthHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

Now i want to add role permission to it, but i can't seem to find a way on how to.
I found some code that worked on older versions, but apparently not on 7.1

```
<handler class="org.wso2.api.authorization.RoleBasedAuthorizationHandler">
   <property name="roles" value="testRole"/>
</handler>
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a new authorization handler for MI. You can find it [here](https://github.com/yasassri/wso2mi-authorization-handler/releases/tag/v1.0.0). If you find any bugs please report them back to the Github project.

Once you add the Jar you can engage the Handler as shown below.

```xml
<handlers>
    <handler class="com.ycr.auth.handlers.AuthorizationHandler">
      <property name="roles" value="admin,test" />
      <property name="authorize" value="true" />
    </handler>
</handlers>
```